# Help Unregistering a Core Block Type in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to unregister core block types in WordPress Gutenberg.

I've used the code provided here:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/extensibility/extending-blocks.md#removing-blocks

But I can't get it to work. I feel like there may be a simple step I am missing?

1. I created a plugin which I activated in my WP theme.
2. In my plugin [clore-blocks] folder I created "clore-blocks.php". It contains:

```
/**
 * Remove certain blocks.
 */
function clore_blacklist_blocks() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'clore-blacklist-blocks',
        plugins_url( 'blocks.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks' ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'blocks.js' ) // Version: filemtime - Gets file modification time.
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'clore_blacklist_blocks' );
```

3. In blocks.js I have only:

```
wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType( 'core/verse' );
```

I thought this would remove the "Verse" block type from being used, but when I go to edit a page with the Gutenberg editor, "Verse" is still there.

When I view the page source from the WP edit page, I can see that my "blocks.js" file is being referenced correctly, but It's just not doing anything... or at least not what I want it to do. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: What do you mean by "a plugin which I activated in my WP theme?" Is your code a plugin, or a theme?

Comment: My code is written as it's own little plugin.

Comment: I am having the same issue. When I do `wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType( 'core/verse' )` (or any other core block type) I get an error in the console that this block type is not registered.

Answer (score 4):

Everything works for me with `allowed_block_types` hook.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types', 'my_function' );

function my_function( $allowed_block_types ) {

    return array(
        'core/paragraph'
    );

}
```

You can insert the above code to your `functions.php` file to a custom plugin. It removes all blocks except the Paragraph block.

More examples here https://rudrastyh.com/gutenberg/remove-default-blocks.html

Comment: This is not always a good solution because it removes _all_ blocks except for a whitelist.

Comment: This isn't the answer the OP was after, but I think it solves the same problem the other way around. As @JakeParis noted, it creates a approved list of blocks instead of removing them one-by-one and this is exactly what I need in my case—just didn't know it until now.

Comment: This hook is currently WP 6.2 deprecated - the recommended one is `allowed_block_types_all`

Comment: Here's the approach using the new allowed_block_types_all 
 hook. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/416581/29136

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem following the code suggestion in the Gutenberg docs.

I solved this by adding a `wp.domReady()` call to the JavaScript code. So, like this:

```
wp.domReady( function() {
    wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType( 'core/verse' );
});
```

Now, the 'verse' block is gone from the block editor.

I think this has to do with the order of loading javascript files in the admin. The `unregisterBlockType` should be called after the block editor has loaded.

Hope this helps!

Thanks to PayteR for the suggestion and see https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#using-a-blacklist for more info.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Correct way is to use wp.domReady() even hook, like it's eplained here https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#using-a-blacklist

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PayteR. That looks like the piece of documentation i needed when solving this myself. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using PHP hook on how to disable specific block on the Gutenberg editor:

```
<?php
function disable_specific_blocks( $allowed_block_types, $post ) {
    // An array of block names to disable
    $disabled_blocks = array(
        'core/table',
        'core/image',
        'core/gallery',
    );
  
    // Use this condition to disable blocks on certain post types, otherwise you can remove this IF condition
    if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
        $allowed_block_types = array_diff( $allowed_block_types, $disabled_blocks );
    }

    return $allowed_block_types;
}
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'disable_specific_blocks', 10, 2 );
?>
```

You can check this guide on [how to restrict specific blocks on the WordPress block editor](https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-disable-specific-blocks-in-the-wordpress-gutenberg-block-editor/) for more information.

Comment: The first argument can (and mostly will) be a boolean value indicating either all blocks are activated (true) or deactivated (false) and your array_diff will fail...